# How to display fast\smooth scrolling dataset on mobile app?

Tags: delphi, mobile, firemonkey

I am developing a mobile app for Android\iOS, and I need to display a dataset with multiple columns. I can easily do this with a TGrid + databinding, however, scrolling is extremely slow on mobile devices. TListView is very fast, but unfortunately does not support columns as far as I can see. Using TListView + formatted text is very responsive:

```
LItem.Text := Format('%-10s %-30s %-10s %-30s %-10s %-10s %-10s',
            [Trim(myQry.Fields[0].AsString),
             Trim(myQry.Fields[1].AsString),
             Trim(myQry.Fields[2].AsString),
             Trim(myQry.Fields[3].AsString),
             Trim(myQry.Fields[4].AsString),
             Trim(myQry.Fields[5].AsString),
             Trim(myQry.Fields[6].AsString)]);
```

However, our company policy specifies the use of Calibri, and so the alignment is all over the place.

Does anyone know of a method to display a dataset on mobile apps with multiple columns that is responsive with smooth scrolling?

Comment: Pretty sure TListbox supports multiple columns

Comment: Thanks ThisGuy, your comment lead me to the solution. It's not as fast on mobile devices as TListView but still a huge improvement over my other attempts. Do you want to answer my question so that I can set it as Answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a Tlistview or grid, implement a TListbox. You are right OP, in that it is not as fast/smooth as a TListview when scrolling, but if you work well with styling, then it can still be ideal.